# Glyph icons is not displaying even it contains bootstrap file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I like to use some kind of glyphicons in my page,But it is not showing,But when
tried the below ,(attached images of View with and without this reference )
     
 in my page the whole page changes,i have the bootstrap.min.css page file,and am also tried calling this file,But still it is not working ,Any solution?

**Code**

```
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" style="color:@s.mcolor"></span>
```

[image: With the reference]

[image: Without reference]

Comment: Can you please share the HTML where you refer glyphicons?

Comment: @Mohan Ramalingam updated ma question,Please take a look sir

Comment: Can you please try removing the in-line style `style="color:@s.mcolor“`

Comment: @Mohan Ramalingam yes i tried,But not working,And  that code snippet is necessary for ma page

Comment: Have you mentioned the viewport correctly? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Yeah, have tried,Please have a look at the pictures attached,The thing s that when am using the online reference my page font size has become too small